# Declare variable in first statement then set as parameter in second

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute two lines of code in my SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT SUM(paid) AS sumpaid FROM clipaid WHERE event='010101-01' AND year=2014;
UPDATE event SET totalpaid = sumpaid WHERE event='010101-01' AND year=2014
```

In the first line I would like to declare variable `sumpaid` and update this variable as parameter in second statemnt.

I'm getting this error: `Invalid column name 'sumpaid'`

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a variable

```
declare @sumpaid int
SELECT @sumpaid = SUM(paid) FROM clipaid WHERE event='010101-01' AND year=2014;
UPDATE event SET totalpaid = @sumpaid WHERE event='010101-01' AND year=2014
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare a **variable** like this:

```
declare @varSumPaid int
```

and the assign it value like this:

```
SELECT @varSumPaid = SUM(paid) 
FROM clipaid 
WHERE event='010101-01' 
AND year=2014;
```

and in update query use it like this:

```
 UPDATE event 
 SET totalpaid = @varSumPaid 
 WHERE event='010101-01' 
 AND year=2014;
```